# Не могу добавить заголовок 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' в GET request для кроссдоменных запросов.JS код

Tags: javascript, c++, get, cors

Не получается отправить заголовок Get запроса из Arduino/ESP-01 на локальный сервер методом `client.print()`. В случае `php file_get_contents();` все работает. При запросе в JavaScript ответ блокируется CORS.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.0.102/datasend?key=123'
>   from origin 'http://192.168.0.101' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Есть два сервера в локальной сети(оба имеют веб-интерфейс). Сервер Arduino который принимает запросы и высылает данные в ответ и локальный-сервер-ноутбук который обрабатывает эти данные.

Проблема не возникало когда сервер передает запросы на свой веб-интерфейс.
Код на сервере Arduino(нажатие кнопок обрабатываются js кодом, который посылает GET запрос на сервер):

```
function refreshDataStream() {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://192.168.0.102/datastream?key=123', true);
    request.onload = function() {
          let data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
          document.getElementById('ValueOfSensor_1').innerHTML = data.v2;
          document.getElementById('ValueOfSensor_2').innerHTML = data.v3;
            console.log(data);
    }
    request.send(null);
}
```

Код на стороне сервера, реагирует на обращение:

```
  HTTP.on("/datastream", DataStreamToHTTP); //При HTTP запросе вида http://192.168.4.1/datastream?key=123
  HTTP.on("/datasend", DataSendToHTTP);     //При HTTP запросе вида http://192.168.4.1/datasend?key=123
  HTTP.onNotFound([](){if(!handleFileRead(HTTP.uri())){handleNotFound();}});
  HTTP.begin();
```

Ответ который отправляет Arduino сервер:

```
void DataStreamToHTTP() {
    client.connect(IP_local, 80); //IPAddress IP_local(192, 168, 0, 101);
    client.print("GET /");
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.print("Host:");
    client.println("192.168.0.101");
    client.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    Serial.println("send to local serv");
    client.flush();     // ждем отправки всех данных
    client.stop();
    //HTTP.send(200, F("text/html"), message);
}
```

Пытался добавить заголовок в headers Get - запроса. Не вышло:
1)При `HTTP.send(200, F("text/html"), message);` отправляет на локальный сервер это с ошибкой CORS:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 9
    Connection: close
```

2)При `client.print` (есть соединение с сервером:`client.connect`) вообще ничего не отвечает ;(

Помогите разобраться какой заголовок куда отсылать. Всем спасибо заранее!

Comment: этот заголовок должен поставить сервер, на ответ, Вы плохо понимаете назначение cors, почитайте про это

Comment: arduino сервер на чем написан?

Comment: Сервер на С++ в Arduino ide. Используется контролер с WiFI ESP-01 на нем и развернут маленький сервер

Comment: на `ESP` еще и сервер...жестоко вы с ним :) попробуйте в инете найти как разрешить `CORS` именно на сервере (можно для всех подряд, а когда разберетесь - то для определденных). На плюсах, к сожалению, никогда не писал серваки.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц я уже пошерстил. Но так и не понял кто должен слать 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin *' сервер который делал запрос или который шлет ответ.

Comment: `cors` должен подставить сервер в ответе. Но тонкостей реализации не могу вам подсказать ) Ожидайте ответа от С++'ников. И своету вам немного изменить теги, и оставить `c++` и `cors`...думаю этого достаточно будет. и добавьте что вы используете для создания сервера (ну там либу какую-то или что) а то у вас не понятно...я бы может что-то поискал сам, но не вижу ничего наводящего